# best practices for return async promise (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I would like to know which path is prefered and why in this method that return a promise of users.

Because I'm a bit lost in which is the best practices and is there a better one!

Is there something that I do not understand ?

## 1

```
getUserList(): Promise<User[]> {
    return userService.getList();
}
```

## 2

```
async getUserList(): Promise<User[]> {
    return userService.getList();
}
```

## 3

```
async getUserList(): Promise<User[]> {
    return await userService.getList();
}
```

**EDIT**

## 1

I know it return the promise to the caller and the caller must manage the promise himself.

## 2

It seem's pretty wierd and i thin the async is useless, but i've seen it often... so that's why it's in the question.

## 3

The promise is resolved in the method and the caller must use try-catch to manage the errors. It may be usefull when the caller is manageing many async call simultaneously... and we want to manage the errors at view level.

Comment: `Is there something that I do not understand ?` Yes, it seems to me you don't fully understand when to use `async` functions

Comment: It's not a very usefull comment ether i guess

Comment: What I meant was if you fully understood why you use an `async` function, you wouldn't have had the confusion

Comment: check my edit, i perfectly know what i know... it's obvious! But what is the best practices people use in their project and why, if you cannot provide usefull informations, you shouldn't comment that way... it won't help any users reading this posts that have the same question to ask.

Comment: Alright zealot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Your first example is correct.

#### 1

```
getUserList(): Promise<User[]> {
    return userService.getList();
}
```

This is the method I would use. Since you're not using `await` in the method body, and assuming `getList()` returns a promise, there is no need to declare the method `async`.

#### 2

```
async getUserList(): Promise<User[]> {
    return userService.getList();
}
```

All `async` methods implicitly return a `Promise`. Consider the following:

```
async getNumber() {
    return 1;
}
```

This actually returns a `Promise<number>`. For this reason, your #2 example is annotated incorrectly and out of the three examples, is the only functionally incorrect one. In reality, this is how the type signature would look given what it's doing:

```
async getUserList(): Promise<Promise<User[]>>
```

**Edit:** According [this](https://javascript.info/async-await) if a promise object is returned by an `async` method it is not re-wrapped in a promise, so this example may be similar to #3 in that declaring it `async` is still functionally correct albeit unnecessary and confusing.

#### 3

```
async getUserList(): Promise<User[]> {
    return await userService.getList();
}
```

This is simply redundant. You are `await`ing the result of a promise, and then implicitly re-wrapping it in a promise before returning it. This would really only be useful if you were `await`ing on more things in the function body, for example:

```
async getUserList(): Promise<User[]> {
    const someRequiredValue = await userService.someOtherThing();
    return await userService.getList(someRequiredValue);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your time, that's what i needed! So most of the time #1 is the best practices, except if the method is doing manipulation on the returned value or do multi requests.